# Visual Studio 2015 Web Deploy to SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-deployment

I was using VS2013 and i could publish successfully to my server which has SQL SERVER 2008. 
Now i installed VS2015 and when i tried to publish my same project i am getting the below error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Web deployment task failed. (Could not deploy package.
Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.) 0
```